# macOS Mojave: Alternating between merging and replacing folders when copying?

Tags: finder, mojave

For some reason macOS Mojave offers me to merge folders some of the times when I copy a folder to a destination that already has one with the same name. Other times a **nearly identical** dialog box pops up where I'm offered to **replace** the folder instead. I don't know why Apple is trying to trick me into overwriting my data like this, but they recently succeeded.

How do I consistently get the option to merge folders?